# Where does Magento store the users locked information?

Tags: magento, locked

Where in the Magento database can I find the information about whether a user is locked or not? I checked all the customer_* tables but could not find something.

Thanks!

Comment: 'Locked Users' as in customer or admin user?

Answer (score 0):

check lock_expires value in admin_user table, reset failures_number to 0 if you need to do that from database level